# Ubuntu equivalent of CentOS success / failure

Tags: command-line, scripts, services, init.d

A lot of services in CentOS look like this (except green and red, respectively):

```
$ sudo service blah start
Starting blah:           [  OK  ]
$ sudo service notrunning stop
Stopping notrunning:     [FAILED]
```

This happens because the `/etc/init.d` scripts use utility scripts in `/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions` called `success` and `failure`. Here's a snippet from `/etc/init.d/sshd` in CentOS:

```
echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
$SSHD $OPTIONS && success || failure
```

My question is: is there a ubuntu equivalent? I could copy the scripts over, but they're more complicated than you'd think, and why reinvent the wheel if I don't have to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the functions you are looking for are sourced from `/lib/lsb/init-functions`, and named `log_success_msg` and `log_failure_msg`:

```
$ . /lib/lsb/init-functions
$ log_success_msg foo
 * foo
$ log_failure_msg foo 
 * foo
```

In this output, the first `*` is grey, the second is red (error case). Not extremely colorful, just enoug to get the point across...

From `/lib/lsb/init-functions`:

```
[ ... ]

log_success_msg () {
    if [ -n "${1:-}" ]; then
        log_begin_msg $@
    fi
    log_end_msg 0
}

log_failure_msg () {
    if [ -n "${1:-}" ]; then
        log_begin_msg $@ "..."
    fi
    log_end_msg 1 || true
}

[ ... ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the functions provided by the `lsb-base` package in `/lib/lsb/init-functions`. I have seen `init.d` scripts sourcing that file and then using the functions within, such as `log_end_msg`:

```
$ (. /lib/lsb/init-functions; log_end_msg 1)
   ...fail!
$ (. /lib/lsb/init-functions; log_end_msg 0)
   ...done.
```

For example, a snippet from `/etc/init.d/ssh` (`case` for `start`):

```
if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid --exec /usr/sbin/sshd -- $SSHD_OPTS; then
    log_end_msg 0 || true
else
    log_end_msg 1 || true
fi
```